# rails simple_form checkboxes reorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I use

```
= f.association :some, as: :checkboxes
```

and got checkboxes like [image]

But I need to reorder by alphabet and draw by columns

I try to reorder with js by counting columns, but faced with situation hen some labels stay near each other in one row, when label no enough long. Maybe js wrong idea and such task can solve by simple_form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= f.association :some, collection: Some.all(order: 'name'), as: :checkboxes
```

A side note - if you would actually use names that are not digits but are character based it should return then alphabetically by default.